# Como faço para retornar um determinado caractere de um texto?

Tags: lua, text

Como faço para retornar um determinado caractere de um texto? Como por exemplo:

```
text = "Eu sou vegano"
```

Como faço para detectar a 5ª letra de `text`? Se alguém me ajudar, ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comando [`string.sub`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial):

```
> string.sub(text, 5, 5)
o
```

Esse comando recebe como parâmetros a string, a posição inicial e a posição final.

Caso a posição final não seja informada, ele assume como a posição final da string. Exemplo:

```
> string.sub(text, 5)
ou vegano
```

Comment: obrigado :)
agora posso fazer o script de animar um texto como se estivesse falando num estilo RPG

Comment: @arthurgps2 De nada!!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta de @Gomiero está super correta. Adicionalmente recomendo utilizar uma biblioteca para manipular strings que usam codificações baseadas em seus bytes.

Isso não é complicado, e é essencial já que normalmente apenas 256 tipos de caracteres podem ser representados no tipo string do Lua, isso é, as strings contém uma sequência de bytes, não de caracteres. Esses bytes são considerados códigos de caracteres.

Vários renderizadores renderizam textos baseando na codificação de texto UTF-8. Algumas linguagens de programação implementam UTF-16 nativamente, porém Lua não seria uma dessas.

Como UTF-8 ou ASCII (eu acho, ASCII...) são comuns, é possível que um código em Lua obtenha caracteres codificados automaticamente através de caixas de texto, de snippets, e principalmente de arquivos.

[Então, sim... é isso aí. Uma string contém uma coleção de bytes em Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1).

Quando meu notebook for consertado, talvez tentarei melhorar minha resposta.

## UTF-8

A versão 5.3 do Lua já oferece uma biblioteca ([utf8](https://lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5)) para trabalhar com UTF-8 às strings, inclusive uma síntaxe de `\u{código}` quase semelhante ao do ECMAScript, só que codificando um caractere em UTF-8, e apenas usável em strings onde o \ é especial.

A biblioteca só não possui uma função tipo sub, mas dá para fazer uma cópia usando seus métodos:

```
do
    local offset, sub = utf8.offset, string.sub;

    function utf8:sub(i, j)
        i, j = tonumber(i) or 1,
               tonumber(j) or -1;

        local len = utf8.len(self);

        i, j = ( i < 0 ) and ( ( len + 1 ) + i ) or i,
            ( j < 0 ) and ( ( len + 1 ) + j ) or j;

        i, j = ( i < 1 ) and 1 or i,
            ( j > len ) and len or j;

        if ( j < i ) then
            return '';
        end

        i, j = offset(self, i),
            offset(self, j + 1);

        return sub(self, i, j - 1);
    end

end
```

Daí o uso fica assim:

```
print(
    utf8.sub('wowow䀀3', 6, 6) --> 䀀
);
```

O Love2D também suporta a mesma biblioteca ([documentação](https://love2d.org/wiki/utf8)), porém não sei se a versão Lua é equivalente.

E há um projeto no GitHub que oferece uma biblioteca similiar, com poucas diferenças ([Stepets/utf8.lua](https://github.com/Stepets/utf8.lua)) e já oferece uma função sub.

## UTF-16

Um dia tentei fazer uma biblioteca para manipular UTF-16. Ela foi feita de qualquer jeito só para eu ver se funcuonava. Além disso está incompleta, mas quando meu notebook for consertado talvez recriarei: [utf16](https://github.com/hydroper/lua-utf16/blob/master/utf16.lua).

**Por enquanto ainda não sei outras codificações..**