# Como apagar um determinado dado de uma listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

O app tem dois buttons que ao serem clicados adicionam um item a uma listView (arco e espada), porém gostaria que se o item de cada button já estivesse presente no listView, o mesmo fosse apagado.

```
package genesysgeneration.list;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnArco, btnEspada;
    private ListView lvItens;
    private ArrayList<String> itens;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itensAdapter;
    private int cont01, cont02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cont01=0;
        cont02=0;

        lvItens=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvItens);
        btnArco=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnArco);
        btnEspada=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEspada);

        btnArco.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEspada.setOnClickListener(this);

        itens = new ArrayList<String>();
        itensAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, itens);
        lvItens.setAdapter(itensAdapter);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnArco:

                if (cont01==0){

                    cont01=1;
                    itens.add("Arco");
                    itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {

                    cont01=0;
                    //apagar "arco"

                }

                break;

            case R.id.btnEspada:

                if (cont02==0){

                    cont02=1;
                    itens.add("Espada");
                    itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {

                    cont02=0;
                    //apagar "Espada"

                }

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Utilizei uma variável int, pois foi o raciocínio que me surgiu, porém não encontrei o comando para que o item em específico fosse excluído. Olhei essa questão [Como faço para retornar um determinado caractere de um texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172215/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-retornar-um-determinado-caractere-de-um-texto), ela me deu ideia de um **getPosition**, mas é em LUA.

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.list.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Espada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnEspada" />

    <Button
        android:text="Arco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnEspada"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnEspada"
        android:id="@+id/btnArco" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEspada"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvItens" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Você quer excluir o item clicado no listview?

Comment: Não, ao clicar no button, se ele (item )já existir na listView.

Comment: Coloca seu XML activity_main

Comment: Viu a resposta?! Conseguiu resolver ai?!

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A lógica é bem simples**. Basta verificar se o elemento que está a inserir já existe na sua lista usando o método [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)). Se não existir, você insere, caso contrário, você remove. Veja o exemplo para o primeiro caso:

```
if (itens.contains("Arco"))          // verifica se existe
    itens.remove("Arco");            // remove     
else itens.add("Arco");              // adiciona
itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // atualiza o adaptador caso haja mudanças
```

Answer (score 1):

Como Ack Lay falou, podes usar o método **remove**. Porem eu so faria uma alteração no algoritmo do Ack Lay, trocaria o if contains por equais, conforme exemplo:

```
if  (itens.equals("Arco"))          // verifica se existe
    itens.remove("Arco");            // remove     
else 
    itens.add("Arco");              // adiciona

itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // atualiza o adaptador caso haja mudanças
```

Com o comando contains, caso exista um registro chamado "Arco1" ou qualquer coisa que comece com "Arco" o if vai retornar true, e acabar removendo indevidamente. Equals = igualmente/igual.

Comment: Peterr,`itens` é um `ArrayList` e não pode comparar se um `ArrayList` é igual a uma `string`, usando o método `equals()`. A logica certa é, você comparar `array` com `array` e `string` com `string`. O método `contains()`, como propriamente dito, verifica se já contém um item com este nome dentro da lista.

Comment: Aqui não deu certo com o ".equals". FIcou adicionando repetidamente e não excluiu os já existentes.