# Como modificar uma ListView presente em outra activity sem usar Intent?

Tags: android, listview

Criei uma listView na activity inicial de um projeto, e gostaria de saber como modificá-la de outras activitys, sem ter de ficar usando o "**intent.putExtras**".

**Activity01 (onde está a listView):**

```js
package genesysgeneration.lvatt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ListView lvItens;
    public ArrayList<String> alsItens;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> aasItens;
    private Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvItens=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvItens);
        alsItens=new ArrayList<String>();
        aasItens=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        lvItens.setAdapter(aasItens);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Activity02 (uma das activitys que a modificam):**

```js
package genesysgeneration.lvatt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnArco, btnEspada, btnBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        btnArco=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnArco);
        btnEspada=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEspada);
        btnBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        btnArco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alsItens.add("Arco");
                aasItens.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        btnEspada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alsItens.add("Espada");
                aasItens.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent it = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Observem que coloquei nos "sets" de cada Button a modificação que gostaria que acontecesse (**isso funcionaria se tudo estivesse na mesma activity**).

Gostaria que as modificações acontecessem no momento em que cada um dos botões fossem clicados (setOnClickListener) e que a listView estivesse atualizada e correta independente da activity anterior.

A activity inicial, onde se encontra a **listView**, estará sempre sendo executada.

Comment: Minha sugestão é usar os [resultados de `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) para receber um valor resultante da `MainActivity2` na sua `MainActivity`. O único problema que vejo é precisa finalizar a `MainActivity2` em algum momento informando os itens que devem ser adicionados na `MainActivity`.

Comment: entao a mudança só iria ocorrer quando a main2 fosse terminada?

Comment: Isso, exato, você precisa setar o resultado e finalizar a `MainActivity2` pra outra Activity ser notificada.

Comment: mas eu poderia fazer isso de forma a finalizar a main2 e ir, por exemplo, para uma main3 e mesmo assim a main1 ser modificada?

Comment: Mas você não precisa atualizar a Main indo pra Main3 certo? Só precisa atualizar a Main quando for voltar pra ela, que você faria ao dar back press acho, você teria de interceptar o back press na Main2 e setar o resultado.

Comment: como faço isso?

Comment: vou precisar fazer um pequeno teste e coloco um resposta.

Comment: okay, desde já grato!

Answer (score 2):

Como comentei, a forma mais simples é usar os [resultados de `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) para enviar um resultado da `MainActivity2` para a `MainActivity`.

Usando essa técnica ficaria assim:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnArco, btnEspada, btnBack;
    private ArrayList<String> resultados = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restante do seu código...

        btnArco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resultados.add("Arco");
            }
        });

        btnEspada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resultados.add("Espada");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final Intent resultado = new Intent();

        resultado.putStringArrayListExtra("resultado", resultados);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultado);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_ITEMS = 231;

    // Restante das suas variáveis...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restante do seu código...
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(it, RC_ITEMS);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_ITEMS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> items = data.getStringArrayListExtra("resultado");

            alsItens.addAll(items);
            aasItens.addAll(items);    
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: nn irá precisar do `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Acredito que não, olhando o código fonte do `ArrayAdapter`, ele já faz essa chamada no `addAll`. Mas pode chamar caso precise.

Comment: creio que terei de colocá-lo somente se for fazer verificação de existência, para o caso do item já ter sido adicionado, e não ficar sendo repetido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184756/como-apagar-um-determinado-dado-de-uma-listview

Comment: deu erro na linha => `private static final RC_ITENS = 231;`

Comment: Repetição aí já é outro problema, minha sugestão seria usar um `Set` ao invés de uma lista, o `Bundle` aceita nativamente um `Set` de `String`.

Comment: simsim, isso é assunto de uma outra questão de um outro problema, coisa para ser tratado em uma outra pergunta se for o caso, mas voltando a esse RC_ITENS... tá acusando erro

Comment: Faltou definir o tipo, já editei a resposta com o tipo certo.

Comment: Resultou se eu imediatamente vou da main2 para a main1.
Agora se antes disso eu vou para a main3 ou para qualquer outra activity, nada ocorre.
Também se eu vou da main2 para main1, depois para a main2 e main1 (sendo que na segunda vez eu não adiciono nada) a lisVview aparece vazia.
Gostaria que ela ficasse salva permanentemente enquanto a aplicação estivesse sendo executada.

Comment: Como seu caso é bem mais complexo, não vejo outra alternativa a não ser guardar tudo em um banco local, resolve todos os problemas, apesar de exigir um pouco mais de complexidade na solução também.

Comment: hmmmm algum link ki possa me recomendar para que eu possa resolver tal impasse? não quero tomar o seu tempo mais doq jah tomei, seria abuso

Comment: Nada, só não consigo postar uma resposta agora pq vai tomar um bom tempo, mas essa documentação é bem rica: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html. Só tome cuidado para não fazer acesso a banco na Main thread para não ter problemas.